# Need to insert image into auto-response email using HTML and block it from displaying href url for the image, using mail server on HostGator

Tags: html, css, image, email, url

I am trying to setup an auto-response email for our business that will display our business logo image.  Our mail server is hosted on HostGator and I'm using the cPanel auto-responder setup to create this message. I am using html using img tag to insert the image, which is loading fine, however the problem I'm running into is that below the image the email prints out the url of the image.

I am wanting to prevent the url from showing up.  I assume this is an issue with HTML/CSS in the HostGator side of things but don't know where to find it to change it, hoping there is an easier inline CSS formatting that can be done to hide the href url?

The code I am utilizing currently:

```
<div>
<img src="http://www.centralmophysicians.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/LogowithBorder2012color1.jpg" alt="Central Missouri Physicians for Women" style="width:179px;height:228px" />
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be to use the CSS `background` or `background-image` attribute as you can see below.

```css
.image {
  background-image: url("http://www.centralmophysicians.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/LogowithBorder2012color1.jpg");
  width: 179px;
  height: 228px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
<img class="image" alt="Central Missouri Physicians for Women"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for....still getting the URL of the image printed below, and now instead of the image I just get the alt text.

Comment: The URL of your image directs to a 403 error (access forbidden on HostGator), maybe this is where your issue comes from?

Comment: You must have incorrectly copied the address because I just copied and pasted from above and it loaded fine.  Typed the address in on my mobile device and it loaded fine as well.

Comment: Try to access the URL while in Incognito mode under chrome (CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + N) or delete your browser's cookies and access the URL. You are not seeing the 403 error because you are most likely logged in to your HostGator service